# SQL Server: pass datatable to stored procedure with a null value

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, datatable

I have created a user-defined table type in SQL Server and passed as parameter to a stored procedure.

From C#, I create a `DataTable`, then I populate it with the same number of columns as that in the table type in SQL Server, also column types are the same.

This table type I have created in SQL Server allows for null values for some columns, so from C# when I do not need to set them I set as null type.

Then from my stored procedure I do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [MySP] 
    @Data MyDataType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO OneTable
        SELECT *  
        FROM @Data
END
```

My question is: what does SQL Server do when it finds a column in the user-defined table as null? Will it recognize C# null type and automatically insert into the target column table `OneTable` as a correct SQL Server `NULL` value?

Comment: This isn't a DataTable. It's a SQL Server table type. SQL Server will NULLS the same way it treats nulls in tables and table variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of `System.DBNull` singleton class from C#. This is the same as `NULL` in T-SQL.